# Hallertau: Is this Hersbrucker or Mittelfrüh?

Tags: hops

Sometimes recipes call for the use of Hallertau hops. Since this is a region, I'm wondering which variaty is called for: Hallertau Hersbrucker or Hallertau Mittlefrüh?

(I excluded Hallertau Tradition as this is mostly refered to as "Tradition".)

Comment: Could you mark one of the posted answers as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Hallertau Hersbrucker is a replacement for the Hallertau Mittelfrüh. It is more disease resistant than the Mittelfrüh. So, from brewing perspective they are probably the same. Growers will of course prefer the Hersbrucker. From the Dutch Wikipedia article it seems that most cultivations of Mittelfrüh have probably disappeared.

But for taste and flavor they should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hersbrucker is a milder strain of hallertau and good for hefeweizens and lagers. Mittelfruh is more of an aroma hop and still low on alpha bittering.                 Many newer versions of hallertau now exist, and have higher alpha numbers but are bred more for aroma  and flavor. Check the alpha numbers for what you're brewing to decide what to use. I personally don't like hoppy beers, so I stick with low alpha hops like german hallertau. Mittelfruh does have great flavor and aroma. Brewdog333